# Help with a solid of revolution problem.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region enclosed by $y = x^3$ and $y = \sqrt{x}$ about the line $x = 1$ using the disks/washers technique.

So far I have: $$\int_0^1 \pi(1-{\sqrt{x}})^{2} - \pi(1-x^{3})^{2} dx$$
$$ = \pi \int_0^1 (1 - 2{\sqrt{x}} + x) - (1 - 2x^{3} + x^{6}) dx$$
$$ = \pi ((-4x^{3/2}/3) - (x^{7})/7 + (x^{2})/2 + (x^{4})/2) \vert_0^1$$
$$ = \pi (-4/3 - 1/7 + 1/2 + 1/2) - 0$$
$$ = (-10\pi)/21$$
The negative value for what is supposed to be a volume for a solid of revolution is throwing me off. Am I correct in the answer?

Comment: You're rotating the solid around a vertical line, which means your radii should be horizontal. If you evaluate things in $y = x$ form, you are getting vertical radii. (You need to use $dy$ in the problem)

Comment: A negative value should "throw you off"--the *volume* of any solid will always be greater than $0$. (Good job at catching/noticing that--many people don't see those ways of checking work.)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to integrate with respect to $y$.  You're stacking the washers, not laying them on their side.  Picture $x=1$ as a spindle, and that you're dropping the washers of the appropriate sizes on the spindle, and centering them there.

So $x=\sqrt[3]{y}$ and $x = y^2$; they intersect at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.  The cube root is larger than the square for $0<y<1,$ so the $y^2$ is your "outer" radius, as it is farther from $x=1$.

$$V = \pi \int_0^1 dy[(1 - y^2)^2 - (1 - \sqrt[3]{y})^2] = \frac{13 \pi}{30}.$$

Comment: I believe the volume is somewhat less: I find $ \ \pi \ (\frac{1}{5} \ - \ \frac{2}{3} \ - \ \frac{3}{5} \ + \ \frac{3}{2} ) \ . $

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  I missed a minus sign.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Easy to do:  I had to re-check my work twice...

Comment: Now your numerator is right; the denominator was correct before.  [OK now!]

Comment: Ahhh, dagnabbit. :)

Comment: Would you mind posting a solution for the shell method about $y = 1$? I seem to have the disks down but this is now giving me trouble.

Comment: Ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Ah.  Looks like you already did!

Answer (score 0):

No,
The integral is $\int_{0}^{1} 2\pi(1-x)|(y_{1}-y_{2})|dx$, which will evaluate positive for any $y$

Comment: Umm... good intention, but the integrand is not enclosed by absolute value signs; rather, it should be something like $y_1^2 - y_2^2$.  This could theoretically evaluate as negative (depending on what we choose for $y_1$ and $y_2$), but because they represent bounds on a volume, it will turn out to be positive.

Comment: Good point noted anorton.

Answer (score 0):

In the "disk/washer" method, the "slices" are always being taken *perpendicular* to the rotation axis.  (The "cylindrical shell" method uses "slices" parallel to the axis of rotation.)  Since you have a "vertical" axis, the radii of the "washers" lie in the "horizontal" direction, so the "slices" are "stacked vertically".  So you will need to invert your functions into functions of $ \ y \ $ and your integration will be with respect to $ \ y \ . $

In this problem, *also* be careful about which function defines the "outer radius" and which, the "inner radius" of the "washers" relative to the axis $ \ x \ = \ 1 \ $ .